# How can I download zip/tar.gz files for all my gitlab repos?

Tags: gitlab, backup, gitlab-api

#### Background

I'm looking to make backups of the code that i have hosted on gitlab. I only need the zip/tar.gz files, not the whole code history. (I have many repositories there so it wouldn't be practical to do this manually)

My OS is Ubuntu 21.04

#### Question

How can I download zip/tar.gz files for all my gitlab repos?

#### What I've found so far

I've tried using [gitlabber](https://github.com/ezbz/gitlabber) but it turns out it only works for gitlab groups, and not personal repos (almost all my projects are personal repos). (Also gitlabber will download the whole repos, not just the tar.gz files)

Answer (score 0):

I found [ghorg](https://github.com/gabrie30/ghorg) which works with GitLab and clones all repos

```
ghorg clone <gitlab_username> --clone-type=user --base-url=https://<your.instance.gitlab.com> --scm=gitlab --token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I would still like to find a better option, which downloads the tar.gz files rather than cloning the repos. Also ghorg relies on brew which is somewhat cumbersome to install on my OS (Ubuntu). It would be better if there is a quicker/easier option

Answer (score 0):

To download all your repos you could use the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCESS_TOKEN=$1
GITLAB_URL=$2
BRANCH=$3

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" $GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects?owned=true | jq '.[] | "\(.id) \(.name)"' | sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' | while read line
do

PROJECT_ID=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f1)
PROJECT_NAME=$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f2- )

curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN" "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/repository/archive.zip?sha=$BRANCH" -o "$PROJECT_NAME".zip
done
```

You pass your access token, gitlab url and the desired branch

Execution exmple:

```
./get_archive.sh "access_token" "https://gitlab.example.com" "master"
```

Output:

It will download all the code for the repos that you own in format `repo1_name.zip` `repo2_name.zip`